# How to easily share an executable .jar file?

Tags: java, executable-jar, sharing

I have a .jar file that I would like to somehow package with a few videos and send to many different people for comments. (Specifically the .jar file is part of a learning module/virtual lab setup for teaching modular cloning techniques, and I would like to be able to send this out to biology teachers and students).

Ideally, I want to put everything in a website so that people can "play" the .jar file directly from the website and watch the videos, but I haven't figured out how to do that. (For some additional context, this is part of an iGEM project, and we have a wiki page based on mediawiki to add things to, but they do not allow any .jar files to be uploaded because of the security risks.)

I worry that simply emailing the .jar file would be a security risk, because although I did not intentionally create a virus, there's always the risk that I could have.

What is the best path forward to take? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: This is pretty [off-topic for Stackoveflow](/help/on-topic), but: no one can play .jar files from the web, because Java got removed from every browser because it was _incredibly_ insecure. But that doesn't stop you from just setting up a website and giving people a download link. There are millions of free and cheap hosts, even including things like github/gitlab pages, etc

Comment: Ah okay thank you so much!! My apologies--I see what you mean about this not being on topic for stack overflow: thank you so much for answering though!!

Comment: A lot of people use github for this.  Reading through your requirements, I don't see a particular reason for choosing anything else.